# win10 RDP multiple desktops feature

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I'm frequently using remote-desktop with a windows 10 server and access the multiple desktops feature (i.e. similar to linux, in windows win+tab, right-hand corner: new desktop). However if I connect to the server from a machine with different monitor configurations (i.e. only one screen instead of two), the virtual desktops put all windows into the first virtual desktop.

It's highly disorienting, didn't find any solutions with google. Any advice/hints as to how to deal with this properly? There's no apparent reason to me why the number of effective screens should mess with the virtual desktops...

Thanks

Comment: I had this problem, too. And like you I couldn't find a "real" solution (there are some tricks, but nothing perfect). So I asked a similar thing in the VDI enterprise community and got a "for backwards compatibility reasons this is not possible".

Comment: This might be specific to windows server edition, as I'm not having this issue with my personal RDP onto my personal laptop (win10). Updates follow...

Comment: VDI means "Virtual Desktop Infrastructure" - all the clients are Windows 10. Hopefully it gets fixed with 19H1 as 1809 does have better window management, but not perfect desktop management. 19H1 **should** be better.